# PHP: If $_GET then bold it

Tags: php

```
echo '<a href="?view=new&days=2">2</a> • <a href="?view=new&days=4">4</a> • <a href="?view=new&days=7">7</a> • <a href="?view=new&days=14">14</a> • <a href="?view=new&days=30">30</a> days';
```

I have this as a "submenu", for showing newest members. You can choose for how many within days you want to see the newest users on the site.

Its much repeating myself, the only thing that is changing is days=30 in the link, and "30" as linktext.

Now I would like to check if $_GET["days"] == 2, then bold it, `<strong>2</strong>`.

I could do this myself, but then it would be just duplicating it all, and in every link do the $_GET["days"] == 1, $_GET["days"] == 2, $_GET["days"] == 3..

Isnt there a smarter way to do this without repeating myself all the time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this:

```
$days = isset($_GET['days']) ? $_GET['days'] : 2;
$daysArray = array(2, 4, 7, 14, 30);
foreach ($daysArray as &$val) {
    if ($days == $val) {
        $val = '<a href="?view=new&amp;days='.$val.'"><strong>'.$val.'</strong></a></b>';
    } else {
        $val = '<a href="?view=new&amp;days='.$val.'">'.$val.'</a>';
    }
}
echo implode(' • ', $daysArray);
```

Here the [conditional operator `cond ? expr1 : expr2`](http://php.net/language.operators) is used to assign either the value of `$_GET['days']` or `2` to `$days` depending on whether `isset($_GET['days'])` is true or false. With using `&$val` in [`foreach`](http://php.net/foreach), `$val` is a reference to the actual value in `$daysArray` so that changing `$val` inside the `foreach` will also change the value that it references in `$daysArray`. That means after the `foreach` loop `$daysArray` is an array of links that are then put together using  `•`  as separator.

This might not be the most concise solution but it fulfills the requirement. As other already mentioned, you might consider using an unordered list instead and display it as a single line list with the bullet separators using CSS instead:

```
ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
ul > li {
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
}
ul > li + li:before {
    content: '•';
    margin: 0 0.35em;
}
```

In fact, I would prefer that too.

Comment: Nice solution. I got few question just to expand my knowledge. What are you doing in $days? A boolean? and why : 2; ? and the foreach you have $daysArray as &$val <-- What does this mean?

Comment: The `?` and `:` together form the conditional operator.  It splits the statement up into three parts: the condition, the value if the condition is true, and the value if it's false.

Comment: `cond ? expr1 : expr2` is the conditional operator (just google it). And using `&$val` makes `$val` a reference to the original value in `$daysArray`.

Comment: The `&` in `&$val` makes `$val` a reference to the actual value in the array.  When you do that, changing `$val` will change the value in the array.  Without it, you'd just change your local copy of the value, leaving the array unmodified.

Comment: What’s the reason for the down vote? Is anything wrong with this?

Answer (score 0):

With an array ?

```
$days = isset($_GET['days']) ? intval($_GET['days']) : 2;

foreach(array(2,4,7,14,30) as $day) {
echo '<a href="?view=new&days='.$day.'">'.($day===$days ? '<strong>'.$day.'</strong>' : $day).'</a>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have an array with all the values:

```
$days = array(2, 4, 7, 14, 30);
```

and create the list like so:

```
<ul>
<?php foreach($days as $day): ?>
    <li>
    <a href="?view=new&days=<?php echo $day ?>">
        <?php echo (isset($_GET['days']) && $_GET['days'] == $day) "<strong>$day</strong>" : $day; ?>
    </a>
    </li>
<?php endforeach;?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Although I very like this approach, `isset($_GET['days'])` seems very misplaced in the View. as well as `echo`

Comment: just because it's data preparation. All data should be ready before calling template. Or you will spoil the whole idea of business/presentation logic separation.

Comment: @Col: There was no mention of any separation... I don't know the rest of the OP's code. I don't know if he is using MVC or not. So I give him the nearest *possible* solution with the given code. And I know that you like short open tags, but that does not mean that `echo` is misplaced...

Comment: I didn't mean echo variables but "long" echo with HTML tags in it. And I don't question your solution but merely leaving my comment. You DID that separation, but unfinished it

Answer (score 0):

make a loop :

```
$days = array(2, 4, 7, 30);
foreach($days as $day){
  $label = $_GET['days'] == $day ? '<strong>'.$day.'</strong>' : $day;
  echo '<a href="?view=new&days='.$day.'">'.$label.'</a>';
}
```

Plus you should use a CSS class instead of using strong tag :

```
$days = array(2, 4, 7, 30);
foreach($days as $day){
  $attr = $_GET['days'] == $day ? ' class="active"' : '';
  echo '<a href="?view=new&days='.$day.'"'.$attr.'>'.$day.'</a>';
}
```

CSS should be like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
 .active{ font-weight: bold}
</style>
```

This way you will later be able to change the appearance of the active link without modifying your PHP code

Answer (score 0):

here is mine 5 cents.
everyone here is talking of MVC but almost no one using it in their examples.

first we have to prepare all required data.

```
<?
$day_vars = array(2, 4, 7, 14, 30);

if (!isset($_GET['days'])) $_GET['days'] = 2;
$key  = array_search($_GET['days'], $day_vars);
$days = $day_vars[$key];
?>
```

and then output in using a template
(partly based on Ben's good suggestion)

```
<ul>
<? foreach($day_vars as $day): ?>
  <li>
   <a href="?view=new&days=<?=$day?>"<? if($days == $day): ?> class="active"<? endif ?>>
    <?=$day?>
   </a>
  </li>
<? endforeach ?>
</ul>
```

as for the • character, all appearance should be made using CSS features.